# Must you share licensing information for library dependencies?

Tags: licensing

I'm not sure where on the Stack Exchange to ask this question.

If one of your project's dependencies is dependent on another library, do you share both licensing information?

For example, if my application uses `Library A` that is dependent on `Library B`, but *my code* doesn't depend on `Library B`, do I share licensing information for it (it as in `Library B`)? Do I attribute credit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subject to the licenses of everything included in your program, whether included directly or indirectly (i.e. a dependency of a dependency). You'll have to check each license to see what obligations each imposes on you - some require disclosure to recipients, some don't.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Just to be sure, all the code that *I write/create myself*, regardless of the fact that it uses third-party libraries, can be licensed however I see fit?

Comment: It depends on the specific license. Some, like the GPL, require the whole program to be under the same terms (which is why the LGPL was created), others have different terms.